# CLLocationManager update locations in OS 5 & iOS6 (which should we use?)

Tags: ios, ios6, cllocationmanager

I've been developping an iPhone app, and with recent release of iOS 6, our client demanded us to make the app should support the new iOS (the app was been developed as iOS 5 app).

Our app runs almost fine for both iOS 5 & iOS 6 (except several issues I'm having now). However, I just noticed that the method which I'm calling in AppDelegate for CLLocationManager:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

is deprecated, and in iOS 6 we should use the following method instead:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Sure, we can (and I would like to) use this method. But my client demanding us that we must make the app to support both iOS 5 & iOS 6 (yes, I know it's reasonable "demand" anyway).

To enable Core Location support both iOS 5 & iOS 6, which method I should have write in my code? Is there any way to put some "if" like conditional statements?

I'm sorry for interrupting the community with these simple stupid question, but I have no firm background with Objective-C and iPhone programming, and I'm still learning (I do have some experience in Java, but this is my first time to develop a "real" app).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 
`-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`

and set `Deployment Target` to 5.0 in target properties-> summery tab. it will work fine with iOS 5 & iOS 6

Comment: Thank you for quick and precise answer! So, even deprecated method still effective?

Comment: this method is deprecated in iOS 6 and above. if u set deployment taget to iOS 5.0, your app will build as base SDK iOS 5.0 so it will work fine.

Comment: @ShineethHamza: If you set the deployment target to iOS 5, will it show a compiler warning when you run the app on a iOS 6 device? What happens if I write both the delegate methods in my class?